# Trying to extract y_val from dataset throws "all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions"

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am very new to machine learning and python in general. I'm working on a project requiring to make an image classification model. I've read the data from my local disk using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` and now I'm trying to extract `x_val` and `y_val` to generate a `skilearn.metrics.classification_report` with.

The issues is that whenever I call:

```
y_val = np.concatenate([y_val, np.argmax(y.numpy(), axis=-1)])`
```

I get the following error and I have no idea why or how to fix it

> y_val = np.concatenate([y_val, np.argmax(y.numpy(), axis=-1)])
> File "<**array_function** internals>", line 5, in concatenate
> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)`

Here's my code

```
#data is split into train and validation folders with 6 folders in each representing a class, like this:
#data/train/hamburger/<haburger train images in here>
#data/train/pizza/<pizza train images in here>
#data/validation/hamburger/<haburger test images in here>
#data/validation/pizza/<pizza test images in here> 

#training_dir = ......
validation_dir = pathlib.Path('path to data dir on local disk')

#hyperparams

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  training_dir,
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  validation_dir,
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)
print(val_ds.class_names)

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

normalization_layer = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)

resize_and_rescale = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(img_height, img_width),
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)
])

#normalization, augmentation, model layers

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

start_time = time.monotonic()

epochs = 1
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)

#plot

#testing random image
test_path = pathlib.Path('C:/Users/adi/Desktop/New folder/downloads/hamburger/images(91).jpg')

img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    test_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
)
img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

print(
    "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
    .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
)


x_val = np.array([])
y_val = np.array([])
for x, y in val_ds:
  x_val = np.concatenate([x_val, np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)])
  y_val = np.concatenate([y_val, np.argmax(y.numpy(), axis=-1)])        #<----- crashes here

print(classification_report(y_val, x_val, target_names = ['doughnuts (Class 0)','french_fries (Class 1)', 'hamburger (Class 2)','hot_dog (Class 3)', 'ice_cream (Class 4)','pizza (Class 5)']))
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error and how I can fix it. Or alternatively how can I get what I need to make classification_report work. Thank you.

Comment: can you show us a couple of elements from val_ds?

Comment: @sk877 ok. how do I do that? or are you referring to the images?

Comment: just try to print(val_ds[0:3]) or something, and reduce 3 if the arrays are too long.

Comment: also, unrelated but good to adjust early on... it reads weird to evaluate a model (with a classification report) between "x_val" and "y_val". you are evaluating actual y against predicted y, so maybe consider renaming your variables to y_pred and y_act or something, otherwise people will cry

Comment: @sk877ok. I'll rename. thank you. tried to print. give me a `TypeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `argmax` operation while getting the true classes.

Since you did not specify `class_mode` in [tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory), labels are sparse which means they are not one-hot-encoded.

If you had one-hot-encoded vector labels, above code of yours would be correct.

Another thing is that renaming your arrays should be better like this and when predicting one image at a time, you can use `model(x)` which is more efficient. Correct code should be:

```
predicted_classes = np.array([])
labels = np.array([])

for x, y in val_ds:
  predicted_classes = np.concatenate([predicted_classes, np.argmax(model(x), axis=-1)])
  labels = np.concatenate([labels, y.numpy()])
```

Comment: This works. Thank you very much, I spent more than half a day on this. I'm off now to understand what one-hot encoding is.

Comment: Say, you have labels [0], [1], [2] --> 0 represented as [1,0,0] // 1 --> [0,1,0] ... and so on.